# create one to one REFERENCES in EF designer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, database-design, visual-studio-2013

I have two tables employees and aspnetUser. I'm trying to create an Associate between tables employees and aspnetUser in  EF  designer in VS2013 using email from employees and username(email).I createUNIQUE Constraint on employees email to have UNIQUE email for each employee I have Problem when click ok I have this error message "verify that the navigation property name is unique" I have couple of Problems.

1-I try to use ID from asp.net membership but it is varchar(128) not guid  because of that I have to change my employees ID from int to varchar(128) to very table have relation with employees.

2- how to solve this problem apically I don't have access to database because the easy thing is to create REFERENCES CONSTRAINT between users and employees I really don't have access to database because of company  ?

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only way to create a 1:1 association in EF is if the PK of one table is a FK and the PK in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you're introducing new navigation properties with names that already exist in the types you're trying to associate. In the text boxes below the Navigation Property checkbox you're not *selecting* properties. You're entering names for the new ones you've indicated you want to create by checking the checkboxes.

This is not going to work. If the types of the primary keys are different, EF won't be able to create a "soft" association between them (where a "soft" association is one that is not backed by a hard foreign key in the database).

You only option is to manually `join` the two tables whenever you need data from both.

Comment: I think will go with with your idea but I will add  unique CONSTRAINT to make sure I have  unique for each empplyee